# How does the function time() work with with srand from the following code?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner at C and I have a hard time to understand the following code:
It's a code where you pick a random number of cards.

```
srand ((unsigned) time(NULL)); //what does this do exactly? i know that the time function returns the current time but how does that work together with srand function?
                               // also, why does it say unsigned?

printf ("enter number of cards in your hand:");
scanf ("%i", &num_cards);

printf ("your hand:");

while (num_cards > 0)
{
    suit = rand() % NUM_SUITS;
    rank = rand() % NUM_RANKS;
    if (!in_hand[suit][rank]) // this 'if' part, if you say it in a more human friendly way, that would be like if in_hand[suit"[rank] is not equal to...." ?
    
    {
        in_hand[suit][rank] = true; // can't i just put if(!in_hand[suit][rank] = true) ? 
        num_cards--;
        printf (" %c%c", rank_code[rank], suit_code[suit]);
    }
}

printf ("\n");

return 0;
```

}
it's a code from the book A modern Approach where you randomly pick a number of cards.. I'd appreciate it very much for your help!

Comment: What exactly is puzzling you? `srand()` or `time()`?

Comment: Hi, both of them.. i kinda don't get how those functions interact with each other and also i don't know why the data type is an unsigned. and what does do this 'if (!in_hand[suit][rank])' part ? and why the same variable comes again after the curly brackets?

Answer (score 2):

`time` returns the time as the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).

The `srand` function sets its argument as the seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random integers to be returned by rand(). These sequences are repeatable by calling `srand` with the same seed value.

As `time` will always (assuming that you do not call it more frequently than one time per second) return different numbers, the seed will be distinct every time you call `srand((unsigned)time(NULL))` and the pseudo random generator will give different sequences.

Comment: the `(unsigned)` is because the `srand()` function expects a unsigned value and `time() returns a `time_t` variable