# Calculating lowest subtotal of array in C

Tags: arrays, c, c99, subtotal

I want to search for the lowest subtotal of *k* values in an array *z* with *n* elements, filled by user input. This works fine with k==1 but I do not understand why my code does not work for k>1.
My program outputs the wrong index and subtotal.

The function is being called from main, after filling the array with *n* elements of int values in a loop until it's filled, asking for the desired length of *k*.

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>

void lowest_subtotal(int z[], int n, int k){
   int t[]={0};
   int i = 0, position = 0, tempmin;

   if(k==1){ //working 100%
       while(i<n){
           if(z[i]<tempmin){
               tempmin=z[i];
               position=i;
           }
           i++;
        }
   printf("Lowest subtotal on Index %d. (sum: %d.)", position, tempmin);
   }

   else{
       //calculate subtotals
       while(i<=n){ 
           for(int j=0; j<k; j++){
               if(z[i+j]<0){
                   t[i] -= z[j];
               }
               else{
                   t[i] += z[j];
               }
           }
           i++;
       }
    
       //search for lowest subtotal
       i = 0;
       while(i<n-k+1){
           if(t[i] < tempmin){
               tempmin = t[i];
               position=i;
           }
       i++;
       }
       //wrong result of index and sum?
       printf("Lowest subtotal on Index %d. (sum: %d.)",position-k-1,tempmin);
   }
}
    int main(){
    int n,k; //length of vector, length of subtotal
    
    printf("n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    int z[99] = { 0 }; //initialize array
    
    
    printf("input elements:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d",&z[i]);
    }
    
    printf("length of subtotal?: ");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    
    lowest_subtotal(z,n,k);
}
```

Comment: @vnmsc Why a negative value is subtracted t[i] -= z[j];?

Comment: `int t[]={0};` define array `t` with space for **one** element, initialize that single element with `0`.

Comment: You have the number of elements for the array `z` in the variable `n`. Why not use it to define `z` with the proper size instead? As in `int z[n];`?

Comment: On another note, please try to come up with semantically significant variable names, rather than non-descriptive single-letter names.

Comment: Amongst other errors, the value of `tempmin` is used before it is initialized.

Comment: There is no need to store the subtotals in an array.

Answer (score 1):

It will be much easier for you if you split it into separate tasks (functions.

```
long long subtotal(int *arr, size_t size, size_t start, size_t k)
{
    long long result = 0;

    for(size_t index = 0; index < k; index ++)
    {
        result += arr[start + index];
    }
    return result;
}

long long smallestSubtotal(int *arr, size_t size, size_t k, size_t *startpos)
{
    long long result = LLONG_MAX;
    for(size_t start = 0; start < size - k; start++)
    {
        long long sum = subtotal(arr, size, start, k);
        if(result > sum)
        {
            if(startpos) *startpos = start;
            result = sum;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
void lowest_subtotal(int z[], size_t n, size_t k)
{
    size_t index;
    long long subt;

    subt = smallestSubtotal(z, n, k, &index);

    printf("The smallest subtotal of length %zu is %lld at index %zu\n", k, subt, index);
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[SIZE];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(size_t index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        arr[index] = rand();
    }

    lowest_subtotal(arr, SIZE, 15);
}
```

Comment: srand(time(NULL)); <- what does this do?

Comment: @svnmsc or even my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70583744/6110094

Comment: I searched for it but couldn't figure out why you're working with randomness in this case as it doesn't seem necessary

Comment: @svnmsc to generate ***distinct*** test cases on every program run.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the OP code, the task is to find the starting index of `k` *consecutive* numbers in an array of `n` numbers such that the sum of the `k` numbers is minimal.

The case of `k=1` need not be a special case. Besides, the idea of updating the sum of a "window" of `k` elements is good, but there are several errors in the implementation. A working version of `lowest_subtotal()` could be as follows:

```
#include<limits.h>

int lowest_subtotal(int z[], int n, int k)
{
    if(k > n || k < 1)
    {
        return -1;  // Error, k must be in the range from 1 to n 
    }

    // Calculate sum in window at index 0
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        sum += z[i];
    }

    // Slide window and update sum
    int index = 0;
    int min_sum = sum;
    for(int i = 1; i < n - k; i++)
    {
        sum += z[i+k-1] - z[i-1];  // Add incoming value and subtract the leaving value
        if(sum < min_sum)
        {
             min_sum = sum;
             index = i;
        }
    }
    printf("Lowest subtotal at index %d (sum=%d)\n", index, min_sum);
    return index;
}
```

Comment: 1. Wrong type for indexes. 2. Sum very easy can overflow

Comment: @0___________ You are right in both. I will leave this as an exercise as needed for the use case. My main point was to show the correct "sliding window" implementation which gives O(n) performance rather than the O(nk) of the naive implementation.

Comment: I do not think that he wants anything not naive. He is learning basic stuff :). Performnce is less important than avoiding UB pitfalls

Comment: @0___________ Then it is good that the system allows for multiple answers to cover different aspects :-)